# Import Multiple Text with pre-defined header in worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Below script works perfect for importing multiple text files without duplicate header. But, requirement is paste the data in second row of worksheet. In first row, there is **Import** button for calling macro. But, as soon as execution completes first row is vanished and data is pasted.

```
Sub ReadFilesIntoActiveSheet()
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim folder As folder
Dim file As file
Dim FileText As TextStream
Dim TextLine As String
Dim Items() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim cl As Range
Dim sFolder As String, vDB, Ws As Worksheet
Dim rngT As Range
' Get a FileSystem object
Set fso = New FileSystemObject

    ' get the directory you want

    sFolder = "G:\Team Learning\vbapractice\Dunning\Import\"
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(sFolder)
    ' set the starting point to write the data to
    'Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    'Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    Set Ws = Sheets("Data")
    'Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)
    Ws.Cells.Clear
    ' Loop thru all files in the folder
    For Each file In folder.Files
        i = i + 1
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=sFolder & file.Name, Format:=1
        With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
            If i = 1 Then
                vDB = .UsedRange
            Else
                vDB = .UsedRange.Offset(1)
            End If
        End With
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Set rngT = Ws.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2) ' it's lastrow +1
        rngT.Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB
    Next file
    Ws.Range("a1").EntireRow.Delete
    Set FileText = Nothing
    Set file = Nothing
    Set folder = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Seems like your problem is the line `Ws.Range("a1").EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: Although, I believe it is not ethical to post URL of another site, but please forgive me admin of this site. I am having to share URL for sharing related files to this question. Pls check the files using URL- https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/import-multiple-text-with-pre-defined-header-in-worksheet.47326/

Comment: Did you try removing that line?

Comment: Yes ..unable to achieve this.

Comment: Unable to achieve what?  Are you saying nothing different happened after removing that line? Have you tried stepping through your code to see at what point the first line is removed?

Comment: I have already tried. Have you tried?

Comment: I have not - I'm suggesting you try, since it's your question and you already have everything set up.  You're not telling us what happened when you tried though, or answering any specific questions about what happened when you tried it, so at this point I'm not sure I have anything else to offer.

Comment: You may ignore it, waiting for someone who can offer solution. Everything is setup for testing.

Comment: I gave you the solution (removing that line of code, which I just confirmed resolved the problem).